# Changing the video format in Django

Tags: python, django, video

What's the best way to change video format from any to mp4 in Django?

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    video = models.FileField(validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['mp4', 'mov', 'wmv', 'avi', 'flv', 'webM', 'mkv'])])
```

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST' in request.POST:
    form = NewVideo(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save()

else:
    form = NewVideo()
```

All the answers on the forum that I found are from many years ago, either require Celera or don't work. Is there a library, an option in Python that will change eg MOV to MP4? The preferred place of use is models.py or views.py

Comment: [There are wrapper libraries for video transcoding tools such as `ffmpeg`.](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) You should know that transcoding can be computationally expensive, and may not be lossless. That's why services such as Mux.com exist.

Comment: Thank you for your message. Can you provide an example of execution for example above case?

Comment: See the [quickstart](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python#quickstart) for the above link.